# Is it possible for me to only allow rotation while the object is moving?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to check if the rigid body magnitude is not 0 but you are still able to rotate while the car is not moving. I would like it to be allowed when the player is not pressing the forward button but not if it isn't moving.

```
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] float turnSpeed;
    [SerializeField] float maxForwardVelocity;

    private Rigidbody kartRigidbody;
    private float rotateInput;
    private float forwardInput;

    private void Start()
    {
        kartRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        rotateInput = 0f;
        if(kartRigidbody.velocity.magnitude != 0)
        {
            rotateInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turnSpeed;
        }
        

        forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0f, rotateInput, 0f);

        kartRigidbody.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(forwardInput, 0f, 0f));

        if(kartRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > maxForwardVelocity)
        {
            kartRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(kartRigidbody.velocity, maxForwardVelocity);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a threshold:

```
if(kartRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > 0.15f)
{
    rotateInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turnSpeed;
}
```

It may not follow the laws of physics but may achieve what you want. Increase the `0.15f` to "lock" the turning for higher speed if the residual speed from which you want to permit turning on is not high enough.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, a threshold would be useful, but another issue you are only taking input when your speed is nonzero.

This means that if your speed is 0, then your input will never be set to 0 and will remain what it was

I would check for the speed *within* your fixed update, and apply the logic there, but always take in your input

```
float threshold = 0.15f;

...

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(kartRigidbody.velocity.magnitude < threshold)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0f, rotateInput, 0f);
    }

    ...

}
```